# Eigenvalues of traceless random matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, random-matrices

For random matrices we know the eigenvalues have the Wigner semicircle distribution. I wonder what is the distribution of eigenvalues of traceless random real symmetric or Hermitian matrices? This is the case in a problem I am studying.